# How to convert from char[] array to BitSet

Tags: java, bitset

I am using this program:

```
private static char[] toCharArray(final BitSet bs){    
    final int length = bs.length();     
    final char[] arr = new char[length];     
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){         
        arr[i] = bs.get(i) ? '1' : '0';
    }     
    return arr;
}
```

to convert `BitSet` obj to `char[]` array. Now after doing some modification to the `char[]` (addition of some zero) array I want to convert it back to `BitSet` obj. Is there a way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well no idea why you do this, but why not reverse your method?

```
private static BitSet toBitset(final char[] entries){
        final int length = entries.length;
        BitSet bs = new BitSet(length);
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                bs.set(i, entries[i] == '1');
        }
        return bs;
}
```

Edit: 
Since it seems you wanted to fix your method, there is only one way I could think of 
to force the char array to a specific size, but you need to know how many zeros you want
to append to the end, so I rewrote your Method like this:

```
private static char[] toCharArray(final BitSet bs, int expectedBits){
        if(expectedBits < bs.length()){
            expectedBits = bs.length();
        }
        final char[] arr = new char[expectedBits];
        for(int i = 0; i < expectedBits; i++){
            arr[i] = bs.get(i) ? '1' : '0';
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

The Problem with using Bitmap is, it only stores "one"s, so the last entry in the BitSet will always be a "one", and the length will always refer to the last "one" in the BitSet.

For Example:

```
 BitSet bs = new BitSet();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            bs.set(i, false);
        }
 System.out.println(bs.length());
```

Prints out "0" whereas

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet();
bs.set(10001, true); 
System.out.println(bs.length());
```

will print out 10002.

This might help you (But you would need to edit the methods above accordingly):

```
class FixedBitSet extends BitSet {

    private int maxLength = 0;

    public int maxLength(){
        return maxLength;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int bitIndex, boolean value) {
        super.set(bitIndex, value);
        if(bitIndex > maxLength){
            maxLength = bitIndex;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i will definitely clarify my point:while storing bits(binary data) in SQL server there is data loss if a binary value starts with 0 other than 1(all 0's before 1 gets deleted). Now after retriving the data i need to put back those zeros back before doing some logic operations on it.So is the conversion to character array and back.

Comment: its not working properly. If the char [] has values like 00010010.. then while converting to bitset the length becomes less as the first 3 zeros are not included in the bitset. for example if this char[] has length 8 the bs.length() is only 5.

Comment: @JavaBits thats not true, running my function in this example: public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "00101010010000";
        char[] array = test.toCharArray(); 
        BitSet first = BitSetTest.toBitset(array); 
        System.out.println(first.toString()); 
    }

will give me a output {2, 4, 6, 9} which is correct

Comment: @JavaBits you should have told us that you mean your Method doesn't work properly!

Comment: its not that my method works properly its about the BitSet class which does not store the preceeding 0's. Hope i am clear. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a UnitTest to complete a similar task. Came up with the following:

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet(testArrayChar.length);

for (int y=0; y<testArrayChar.length; y++)
{
    if(testArrayChar[y]=='0')
    {
        bs.set(y, false);
    }
    else if(testArrayChar[y]=='1')
    {
        bs.set(y, true);
    }
}
```

Can add throwing exception if a character is something other than 0 or 1.